# Use a constant from the derived class in the base class

Tags: c++

I have the following design:

```
class PureVirtual 
{
    unsigned m_count;  // = 0 in constructor
    void register() {assert(m_count + 1 <= MAX); m_count++;};
};

class A : public PureVirtual 
{enum {MAX = 42}};
```

Except `PureVirtual` doesn't know about `MAX`.

The way that I made it work is by creating `m_max` member of `PureVirtual`, then initializing it to a stupid value (because `gcc` issues a warning if a member is not initialized in the constructor), then set it in the constructor of `A`. And the "best" part is that it can't be made `const`.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: A bit nitpicky, but a "pure virtual" has pure virtual methods and no member variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using virtual functions is better solution to this problem:

```
#include <cassert>

class PureVirtual {
    int m_count;
public:
    virtual int max() = 0;
    void register_() {
        assert(m_count + 1 <= max());
        m_count++;
    };
};

class A : public PureVirtual {
public:
    int max() {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 43; ++i) {
        a.register_();
    }
}
```

`max` can be made protected if it is meant to be hidden. To change the value of max, just override it in the derived class. The advantage of this solution is that max will never have a nonsense solution, and you avoid templates.

Comment: Well caught that 'register' is a keyword. You also beat me to the same answer. +1

Comment: Yes, I couldn't figure out why the compiler kept giving me error messages, until I noticed that it was the wrong color in the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Haha, sorry for the misunderstanding about 'register'. I like this solution because 1) templates are evil and 2) A virtual function allows `A` some control over the value of MAX, e.g. compute it at runtime.

Comment: @Vorac Correction: template -in VS- are evil! Templates are a powerful tool in any compiler that actually implements them according to the standard. Anyway if computation at runtime is required, this would be a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

Define `m_max` member in `PureVirtual`:

```
const unsigned m_max;
```

initialise it in `PureVirtual` constructor:

```
PureVirtual(unsigned max) : m_max(max) {}
```

and pass the value you want from the constructor of inherited class:

```
A() : PureVirtual(42) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your design is broken, because the base class requires information stored in the descendant class. Try using policies or containment instead:

```
template <typename Policy>
class PureVirtual 
{
    enum { MAX = Policy::MAX };
    unsigned m_count;  // = 0 in constructor
    void register() {assert(m_count + 1 <= MAX); m_count++;};
};
```

Comment: A great option when max is constant and known at compile time. Absolutely zero overhead when assertions are disabled.